# Is it possible to collect an iterator to populate a collection backwards?

Tags: collections, rust, iterator

Is it possible to **collect** an iterator such that it populates a collection backwards, such as using `push_front` in a `VecDeque`?

It's possible to collect into a `Vec` and then reverse it, but it seems like it should be unnecessary with data structures explicitly supporting this capability. I'd like to avoid writing an explicit `for` loop if possible.

Comment: With an [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) you should be able to do it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let v: VecDeque<_> = (0..=2).collect_rev();
    assert_eq!(v, [2, 1, 0]);

    let v: Vec<_> = (0..=2).collect_rev();
    assert_eq!(v, [2, 1, 0]);
}
```

You just need a bit of glue code:

```
trait CollectRev: Iterator {
    fn collect_rev<B>(self) -> B
    where
        B: FromIteratorRev<Self::Item>,
        Self: Sized,
    {
        B::from_iter_rev(self)
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> CollectRev for I {}

trait FromIteratorRev<T> {
    fn from_iter_rev(iter: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> Self;
}
```

And implement it efficiently for various types:

```
impl<T> FromIteratorRev<T> for VecDeque<T> {
    fn from_iter_rev(iter: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> Self {
        let mut v = Self::new();
        for i in iter {
            v.push_front(i);
        }
        v
    }
}

impl<T> FromIteratorRev<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn from_iter_rev(iter: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> Self {
        let mut v: Self = iter.into_iter().collect();
        v.reverse();
        v
    }
}
```

> I'd like to avoid writing an explicit `for` loop

Someone has to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to collect an iterator such that it populates a collection backwards, such as using `push_front` in a `VecDeque`?

Yes it is. You can iterate over your iterator with `for_each` and populate your `VecDeque` like this:

```rust
let mut my_deque: VecDeque<i32> = VecDeque::new();
(1..4).for_each(|x| my_deque.push_front(x));
```

---

You can reverse your iterator with the [`rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) method. After that, you can call `for_each` to iterate it in the reverse order or you can collect it to a `Vec` directly since it is already reversed.

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_iterator = vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter();
    let reversed_iterator = my_iterator.rev();
    reversed_iterator.for_each(|x| print!("{}", x));
}
```

Or more idiomatically you can directly reverse it in your `for` loop:

```rust
for i in (1..4).rev() {
    print!("{}", i);
}
```

Your output will be:

> ```
> 321
> ```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a7ad6884a82c52919b25ffa3f5a9bba)

Comment: *can call `for_each` to iterate* — or, more idiomatically, use it in a `for` loop.

Comment: It's probably worth directly addressing this point from OP: *populates a collection backwards, such as using `push_front` in a `VecDeque`*.

Comment: Right, for loops. As I said, I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @Listerone `push_front` is a side-effect that you want to apply to each element of your iterator. There has to be a loop somewhere that calls it, whether it's `for_each()` or `for`. It's a common misconception for people learning mixed-paradigm languages like Rust or F# that loops are inherently a bad thing. If there's a function like `map` that better expresses the semantics of your program then you should use it; but if what you're doing really is "perform a side-effect for each element in a collection", then there's nothing wrong with a loop.